# How to recompile glibc to support an older kernel version?

Tags: kernel, glibc, qemu

So I was trying to work with this kernel source 2.6.34, when I tried to boot it on qemu it reports an error 'FATAL: kernel too old'. I searched online and the solution people gave is to make a new glibc which is compatible with the version I was working with, something like '--enable-kernel', but I don't know how to build it and link it to gcc specifically. How exactly should I do to successfully boot the old kernel?

Comment: "when I tried to boot it on qemu it reports an error" -- what is the "it" in that statement? Your question will have a better answer if you show *actual* boot log.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use glibc 2.23 or earlier for non-x86 architectures, and glibc 2.25 or earlier for x86 architectures.  Using later versions requires substantial porting effort because the support code for older kernels is gone.

Comment: Okay but I am having problem with how to compile and use the right version of glibc, are there any resources you recommend?